# MVC 3 Remote validation: how to debug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery

Folks,

I'm doing remote validation in an ASP.NET MVC 3 context.  Sometimes it doesn't work at first.  The page just sits there after a submit attempt as if validation has failed, but there are no messages and the remote validation routines are never hit on the server.

I have at various times figured out various reasons for this -- parameters specified in the wrong order in the attribute constructor, input fields on the form given the wrong names -- but sometimes I'm stumped for long periods.

Are there any tools or techniques that would make this easier?  Some way to peer into the ajax call results or validation mechanism to tell what error is being thrown (and silently consumed) by what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is your your friend.  Other friends include [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and Debugging consoles of your browsers (typically F12)

Comment: Thanks very much!  But -- and I'm not at my work desk so this is an uninformed question -- where actually do I look?  If jQuery validation fails silently, where can you look to find diagnostic information?  If a remote call fails, where is the result code stashed?  All that aside, thanks very much for the recommendations!

Comment: @AnnL. That depends entirely upon how your ajax method works, what kind of error it is, etc.. You can see the response codes from the HTTP request with the tools i mentioned, that should give you somewhere to start.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that after approximately 7 hours I'm a convert to Fiddler.  So far it's told me everything I needed to know.  Thank you!